# How do I change the file extension for files created in content.mso?

Tags: outlook

One of my user's Outlook create files with the ".com" extension when they view an e-mail that contains JPG. There's no detectable virus or trojan on this computer. However, Comodo is complaining about ".com" files being created automatically. Is there a way to change the file extension so that it doesn't create executable files?

UPDATE: This happens to ALL jpg that I receive, regardless of source.

Comment: It's still a virus - have you tried my suggestions below? Also you could contact comodo support and ask them to analyze the file for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what file you want me to send to Comodo since EVERY jpg is saved with a .com file extension.

Answer (score 1):

If viewing a JPEG results in a '.com' file being created, it's a virus.

Detected or not, it's a virus.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Kieran's answer (and yes that IS a virus)

1. Make sure your virus defs are up to date and rescan
2. Do a full system scan after you have updated virus defs
3. Try another scanning tool, such as [Stinger](http://vil.nai.com/vil/stinger/)

Comment: I have the latest Symantec installed and it have detected no virus. I've ran Stinger (build Nov 24) and found nothing.